# To get the JMX values using the DropWizard metrics-Jvm

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I tried to get the JVM metrics values (MemoryUsageGaugeSet,GarbageCollectionUsageGaugeSet) using the dropWizard library

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Code Implementation.

```
  public static void main(String[] args ){
  MemoryUsageGaugeSet memory = new MemoryUsageGaugeSet();
  Map<String, Metric> memoryMap = memory.getMetrics();
  system.out.println( memoryMap);}
```

The result i got was

{heap.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$8@d16011, non-heap.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$11@cc09904, pools.Code-Cache.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@748032cc, pools.Code-Cache.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@2b6e0423, heap.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$6@203428b7, pools.PS-Old-Gen.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@28b49d0c, total.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$4@5dd7cc84, pools.PS-Old-Gen.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@6438401, total.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$1@7b365ee, non-heap.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$12@be3d4e9, pools.PS-Eden-Space.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@68339afd, pools.Compressed-Class-Space.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@724a6876, pools.Metaspace.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@6ecaffc4, pools.Metaspace.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@7b1b3a68, pools.PS-Eden-Space.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@f8ba384, pools.PS-Eden-Space.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@2e2373db, pools.Compressed-Class-Space.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@17ae8d04, heap.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$9@35c43de3, pools.PS-Eden-Space.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@67013f5c, pools.PS-Survivor-Space.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@520935cc, pools.Code-Cache.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@31ac5424, pools.Compressed-Class-Space.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@25135cd7, pools.Metaspace.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@4b066cf6, pools.PS-Survivor-Space.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@50ba970f, pools.PS-Old-Gen.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@3e4e448, pools.Code-Cache.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$15@3c2ef507, pools.PS-Survivor-Space.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@44374fa8, total.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$2@40b1aace, pools.Code-Cache.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$19@6453d034, pools.PS-Old-Gen.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@2f9e8774, heap.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$5@512ad720, non-heap.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$13@1c80e011, pools.Compressed-Class-Space.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@662841c5, non-heap.init=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$10@3dd6cf53, pools.PS-Eden-Space.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@3a428c1e, non-heap.usage=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$14@21d9632f, heap.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$7@5db28b8, pools.PS-Survivor-Space.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@efcd307, pools.Metaspace.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@20f09cba, total.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$3@4ada5390, pools.Metaspace.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@16982c9b, pools.Compressed-Class-Space.max=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$16@7e94b1a4, pools.PS-Survivor-Space.committed=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$18@5aa5f780, pools.PS-Old-Gen.used=com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet$17@427b7997}

**I got the references of the object, instead i want to get the values of these references. What to do for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get/print the value of an object you need to have the `toString()` implemented in the class and `MemoryUsageGaugeSet` doesn't have it. 
Verify @ [javadoc](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/jvm/MemoryUsageGaugeSet.html)

One way is to extend the class with your own implementation `toString()`.

The other way is to iterate over the map and print each value. You may want to try something like below ..

```
Map<String, Metric> memoryMap = memory.getMetrics();

for (String key : memoryMap.keySet()) {
    Metric m = memoryMap.get(key);
    System.out.println(m.getClass());

    if (m instanceof Gauge) {
        System.out.println(((Gauge<Long>) m).getValue());
    }
}
```

`MemoryUsageGaugeSet` results in the `Gauge<Long>` which is an implementation of `Metric`.

Hope this helps.